# Passing special values to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, special-characters, gif

I'm trying to pass some user generated values to utme parameter to Google Analytics to GIF request. The API says it has to be formated as "5(object*action*label)(value)". What happens when I need to pass one of the symbols used in formatting: ()* ? Is there a way to escape them and pass them to label or other parameters?

http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingTroubleshooting.html#gifParameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good question.

You can see the logic in action by utilizing the `ga.js` libary of Google Analytics

If you do this:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent","test","(*)"])
```

The `utme` parameter gets set to `utme=5(test*('2'1)`

I'm waiting to see how the data gets passed, but my guess is that `'2` and `'1`' are escape characters.

What happens, then, if we do

```
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent","countertest","('2'1"])
```

Then the `utme` is set as `utme=5(countertest*('02'01)`

Very strange.

Comment: It kind of makes sense, because I noticed that it deals with opening bracket fine. I'll try these special codes. Thanks.

Comment: The data came through exactly as passed through in the event call. So, it looks like the `utme` handles the special characters in the above way

Comment: Thanks, yeah, seems to work on my side too: "'" is encoded as "'0", ")" - "'1", "*" - "'2".